# Make a function that loads the model, takes a vector of data, and makes a prediction

Tags: python, regression, pickle, func

I'm trying to train a regression model on the Boston Housing dataset and save the model to disk and then make the Title function.

Below code's is working

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from joblib import dump, load 

boston = load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names)
y = pd.DataFrame(boston.target)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(boston_df, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=17)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(x_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict)

with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
del model
with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    lin_model = pickle.load(file)
```

But when I add it's supossed to work

```
def predicting(x):
    x = pd.DataFrame(x)
    with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        lin_model = pickle.load(file)
        pred = lin_model.predict(x)
        print(pred)
```

But I don't know what structure does 'x' need for this function to work!

```
x = [1,2,4,5,6,3,5,6,7,3,5,6,4]
predicting(x)
```

Like above it says `ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 13 is different from 1)`

Please help?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import os
import pickle
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from joblib import dump, load 
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

boston = load_boston()
boston_df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns = boston.feature_names)
y = pd.DataFrame(boston.target)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(boston_df, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state=17)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(x_test)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_predict)

with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    pickle.dump(model, file)
del model

x, _ = make_blobs(n_samples=3, centers=2, n_features=13, random_state=1)
def preficting(x):
    with open('model.pkl', 'rb') as file:
        lin_model = pickle.load(file)
        ynew = lin_model.predict(x)
        for i in range(len(x)):
            print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (x[i], ynew[i]))
preficting(x)
```

Without the final print but I saw it and thought that was pretty, but here's what I needed! :)